# How to merge two data sets based on the result of matching two columns in R

Tags: r, match

I have two data sets df1,df2

```
> df1
 x1    y1 
  1    5
  1    2   
  1    3     
  1   10

> df2
     x2    y2 
      4    8
      4    7   
      4    9    
      4    3
```

I want to match  `y1`  in `df1` with `y2` in `df2`  ,if there are shared values between them ,I will merge the two data sets
in my **EX** ,`y1` contains `3`  and `y2` contains `3`, so the result  will be :

```
> df3

 x1    y1 
  1    5
  1    2   
  1    3     
  1   10
  4    8
  4    7   
  4    9    
  4    3
```

the merger should be based the condition (**shared values only**) between `y1&y2` , otherwise no

Comment: Just do `rbindlist(list(df1, df2))`

Comment: Thanks Akrun. My question about merge the two sets if there are shared values between y1, and y2 columns only, at least one value ,otherwise no. it is simple example but the original data sets contain more 12000 objects for each one of them.